# App crash "AttributeGraph propagate_dirty" on iOS 14.6/14.7

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, swiftui, uiviewcontroller

I recently got some crash reports. For me, the report has not much information where to search for the problem. The crash reports at the moment only occur on iOS 14.6 and 14.7 but I can't reproduce them on my devices/emulators (especially because I have no idea where to search for the problem)

```
Date/Time:           2021-07-29 22:14:50.9666 -0700
Launch Time:         2021-07-29 22:14:46.3294 -0700
OS Version:          iPhone OS 14.7.1 (18G82)
Release Type:        User
Baseband Version:    1.80.02
Report Version:      104

Exception Type:  EXC_BAD_ACCESS (SIGSEGV)
Exception Subtype: KERN_PROTECTION_FAILURE at 0x000000016fafbff0
VM Region Info: 0x16fafbff0 is in 0x16faf8000-0x16fafc000;  bytes after start: 16368  bytes before end: 15
      REGION TYPE                 START - END      [ VSIZE] PRT/MAX SHRMOD  REGION DETAIL
      MALLOC_TINY              119c00000-119d00000 [ 1024K] rw-/rwx SM=PRV  
      GAP OF 0x55df8000 BYTES
--->  STACK GUARD              16faf8000-16fafc000 [   16K] ---/rwx SM=NUL  ... for thread 0
      Stack                    16fafc000-16fbf8000 [ 1008K] rw-/rwx SM=PRV  thread 0

Termination Signal: Segmentation fault: 11
Termination Reason: Namespace SIGNAL, Code 0xb
Terminating Process: exc handler [4037]
Triggered by Thread:  0

Thread 0 name:
Thread 0 Crashed:
0   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00000001f166d75c thread_start + 12
1   AttributeGraph                  0x00000001cef86234 AG::Graph::propagate_dirty(AG::AttributeID) + 368 (ag-graph-update.cc:191)
2   SwiftUI                         0x00000001ac8574a4 StoredLocationBase.beginUpdate() + 368 (StoredLocation.swift:94)
3   SwiftUI                         0x00000001ac857308 StoredLocationBase.BeginUpdate.apply() + 36 (StoredLocation.swift:78)
4   SwiftUI                         0x00000001ac83310c AsyncTransaction.apply() + 188 (GraphHost.swift:656)
5   SwiftUI                         0x00000001ac833008 GraphHost.runTransaction(_:) + 84 (GraphHost.swift:470)
6   SwiftUI                         0x00000001ac831880 GraphHost.flushTransactions() + 168 (GraphHost.swift:459)
7   SwiftUI                         0x00000001ac2e2008 thunk for @escaping @callee_guaranteed () -> () + 28 (<compiler-generated>:0)
8   SwiftUI                         0x00000001ac77c520 closure #1 in ViewRendererHost.render(interval:updateDisplayList:) + 1100 (<compiler-generated>:0)
9   SwiftUI                         0x00000001ac772c0c ViewRendererHost.render(interval:updateDisplayList:) + 308 (ViewRendererHost.swift:0)
10  SwiftUI                         0x00000001ac90ea78 _UIHostingView.displayLinkTimer(timestamp:) + 196 (UIHostingView.swift:1571)
11  SwiftUI                         0x00000001ac187fac DisplayLink.displayLinkTimer(_:) + 100 (_UIHostingView.swift:464)
12  SwiftUI                         0x00000001ac188014 @objc DisplayLink.displayLinkTimer(_:) + 44 (<compiler-generated>:0)
13  QuartzCore                      0x00000001a8b407b8 CA::Display::DisplayLink::dispatch_items(unsigned long long, unsigned long long, unsigned long long) + 672 (CADisplay.mm:2646)
14  QuartzCore                      0x00000001a8c1f7f4 display_timer_callback(__CFMachPort*, void*, long, void*) + 280 (CADisplayTimer.cpp:166)
15  CoreFoundation                  0x00000001a582fa0c __CFMachPortPerform + 176 (CFMachPort.c:537)
16  CoreFoundation                  0x00000001a585521c __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_SOURCE1_PERFORM_FUNCTION__ + 60 (CFRunLoop.c:1991)
17  CoreFoundation                  0x00000001a585459c __CFRunLoopDoSource1 + 596 (CFRunLoop.c:2131)
18  CoreFoundation                  0x00000001a584e180 __CFRunLoopRun + 2372 (CFRunLoop.c:3146)
19  CoreFoundation                  0x00000001a584d308 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 600 (CFRunLoop.c:3242)
20  GraphicsServices                0x00000001bced0734 GSEventRunModal + 164 (GSEvent.c:2259)
21  UIKitCore                       0x00000001a82cb75c -[UIApplication _run] + 1072 (UIApplication.m:3269)
22  UIKitCore                       0x00000001a82d0fcc UIApplicationMain + 168 (UIApplication.m:4740)
23  SwiftUI                         0x00000001ac7b8380 closure #1 in KitRendererCommon(_:) + 112 (UIKitApp.swift:34)
24  SwiftUI                         0x00000001ac7b830c runApp<A>(_:) + 224 (<compiler-generated>:0)
25  SwiftUI                         0x00000001ac2b0b38 static App.main() + 144 (App.swift:113)
26  MyApp                           0x000000010020e9e8 $main + 24 (<compiler-generated>:3)
27  MyApp                           0x000000010020e9e8 main + 36 (GameCenterLogin.swift:0)
28  libdyld.dylib                   0x00000001a5509cf8 start + 4
```

The `GameCenterLogin` is an `UIViewControllerRepresentable` in my SwiftUI application, doing the GameCenter login. Does the `main` in the last lines mean that the crash appears at the start of the app?

My main method looks like this:

```swift
import SwiftUI

@main
struct MyLittleApp: App {
        
    var preferences = Preferences(UserDefaults.standard)
    var purchaseManager: PurchaseManager
        
    init() {
        #if DEBUG
        if ProcessInfo.processInfo.environment["enable-testing"] != nil {
            let time = ProcessInfo.processInfo.environment["time"] ?? "0"
            preferences.time = Int(time)!
            UIView.setAnimationsEnabled(false)
        }
        #endif
        purchaseManager = PurchaseManager(preferences: preferences)
    }
    
    var body: some Scene {
        WindowGroup {
            MainMenu()
                .environmentObject(preferences)
                .environmentObject(purchaseManager)
        }
    }
}
```

Is it possible that this is a bug in iOS 14.6/14.7? If yes: Is there are way to fix this? If not: Is there a way I can get more information about the crash? Or does anyone have an idea what the problem could be?

I have Xcode 12.5.1, if that matters, but I wasn't able to reproduce it on Xcode 13 Beta either.

Comment: Do you have any dependencies? (CocoaPods, Swift Packages)

Comment: The only Swift package I have is "SnapshotTesting" but only used in the test project. Frameworks I have are "StoreKit", "CloudKit" and "GameKit" for game center and backups. No CocodaPods.

Comment: have you tried opening the report in Xcode? It could give you more info

Comment: Do you mean selecting the crash in Organizer and then click "Open in Project" on the right side? It then shows 5 Threads. Thread 0 only shows "static App.main()", "$main", "main", "start" and I can't click any of this. I am not very experienced in debugging in Xcode but it looks like there is no additional information. The other threads only show "_pthread_atomic_xchb_uint32..."

Answer (score 3):

I can't totally help you out with pointing out to the exact issue out here but here are a few thing I can do for you.

### Identifying the Issue

`EXC_BAD_ACCESS (SIGSEGV)` -> Represents a crash due to a memory access issue that occurred when the app used some memory in an unexpected way.

The reason for this crash is mostly due to

> Dereferencing a pointer to an invalid memory address, writing to read-only memory, or jumping to an instruction at an invalid address.

The main issue pointed out in the log is

`KERN_PROTECTION_FAILURE`

The dereferenced memory address is `0x000000016fafbff0`, with the region containing this memory address identified by the arrow.

The address is located in a special memory region called the stack guard, which is a memory region that buffers the stack of a thread from the stack of another thread.

The PRT column shows the current permission attributes for the memory regions, with `r` indicating the memory is readable, `w` indicating the memory is writable, and `x` indicating the memory is executable.

Because the stack guard region has no permissions, all memory accesses to this region are invalid, and the crash report is identifying this memory access as a violation of the memory protection attributes. The stack guard is just one example of protected memory—there are others types of protected memory regions, with different combinations of the protection attributes.

**This means that we have to look for clues on where the memory access issue is occurring.**

As the backtrace doesn't show:

> objc_msgSend, objc_retain, or objc_release at the top of the backtrace, the crash is not due to a zombie object.

> neither do we have gpus_ReturnNotPermittedKillClient at the top of the backtrace which means no issues with OpenGL ES

As both of these crashes are not present, the chances of finding the reason of the crash is slim.

As the cause of a memory access issue isn’t present in the backtrace. Memory corruption occurred when a memory location was unexpectedly modified. After this modification, another part of your app crashed when it tried to use that memory location. The backtrace shows the code accessing the modified memory, but not the code that unexpectedly modified the memory. **The unexpected modification may have occurred a long time before the crash, so the source of the issue isn’t visible in the backtrace.**

> If you have numerous crash reports with signs of a memory access issue, but with different backtraces, you may have a memory corruption issue.

### Investigate the Crash with Xcode

You not have to use Xcode to continue your investigation. Xcode contains a suite of debugging tools you can use to identify memory access issues as your app runs.

- Address Sanitizer
- Undefined Behavior Sanitizer
- Thread Sanitizer

If your app contains code in Objectice-C, C, or C++, run the static analyzer, and fix all issues it discovers. The static analyzer analyzes your app’s code at build time, and identifies common programming mistakes, including some types of memory management issues.

You have to use the malloc debugging features such as **Guard Malloc** to identify your memory issue as it is hard to diagnose. You enable these tools through the Xcode scheme editor, as described by [Run your app with sanitizers, API checks, and memory management diagnostics](https://help.apple.com/xcode/mac/current/#/devcef23c572).

Comment: Thanks for your response. One problem is that I cannot reproduce the crash on my devices. And additionally I have no Objective-C, C or C++ code in my app. It is completely Swiftui and one `UIViewControllerRepresentable`. Does that mean that the problem is most likely external? The static analyzer does not find anything.

Comment: By external if you mean from some other app that’s highly unlikely iOS and all i-devices run in their own sandboxes. If any external change was made then it’s a bug from Apple’s side. Also if there is a memory leak from some internal framework of SwiftUI it’s again a bug from Apple. If you’re pretty sure that the memory issue is device specific like iOS 14.6 or jailbroken devices then you have only one option and that’s to report this bug to Apple and hope they solve it.